# Predict class label from booster predict() function

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, xgboost

I have a binary classification problem, that is solved quite nicely in Python (train and test accuracies around 90%) on default parameters. The scope of my project is to train in Python some "models" that can be re-used later on in a R library I am writing. This is done through Boosters now, bst.save() and bst.load(). So far, so good.

I can save the booster in Python and reload in R afterwards. Problem is, in Python I have the predict_proba() function that is missing in R!

So naturally, I tried out the predict() function that now only gives me numbers above 0.8? What exactly am I supposed to do with this? How can I obtain the predicted label (0 or 1) from the results in predict() ? I just want to have an array containing predicted 0 or 1 for the data passed in the bst.predict(booster, data) method in R.

Of course, I realize I am probably missing something important. This is why I am turning to you for some help.

The first graph, the plotted result in predict() compared to the predict_proba() in the second graph. [image] [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While training the models in Python, originally, you HAVE to put `objective='multi:softprob', num_class=2` in the model definition. This will give a prob for each class in the Booster. In other words, check this here from the docs:

multi:softprob same as softmax, but output a vector of ndata * nclass, which can be further reshaped to ndata, nclass matrix. The result contains predicted probabilities of each data point belonging to each class.

Of course, when using the model trained in Python in R, don't forget to pass the data in the same format (same order, ...) as in Python. As you are using the booster class, a lot of helpers present in the SKLearn interface are missing, so there is no double check of whether you are passing the columns in the same order and everything. I just order the columns alphabetically wrt. a certain language (C for example) and reorder it in R when "testing" the model